# Case-insensitive URLs with JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Is there any easy way to provide a case-insensitive URLs in a JAX-RS web service? The goal of this is to produce a web service which is a "lenient acceptor."<sup>1</sup>

I imagine it's possible to do this with a filter which `.to[Lower|Upper]Case()`s all incoming URLs. Unfortunately, this implementation demands programmer discipline/consistency in making sure that *all* hard-coded URL strings in the application are strictly [lower|upper]case.
 Also, I don't yet know the JAX-RS analog to a servlet filter.

If it matters, I'm using Jersey as my JAX-RS implementation.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>As in, *"be lenient in what you accept, and strict in what you produce"* (can't recall the source)</sub>

Comment: You can put servlet filters in front of a JAX-RS engine (or you can with CXF; that's how I handle my security via a hook to Spring Security).

Comment: Postel's law http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle   However, servers should provide URLs to be followed by clients, using hypermedia, therefore the "strict in what you produce" should apply here.  The HTTP spec RFC 2616 says that the http URLs should be case sensitive except for the scheme and the host.

Comment: @Darrel: thanks for the link, and you make a good point. I'll see what the folks upstairs have to say on the matter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is No, since basically URIs according to [RFC 3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) are case sensitive:

> 6.2.2.1.  Case Normalization
>
> For all URIs, the hexadecimal digits within a percent-encoding
>      triplet (e.g., "%3a" versus "%3A") are case-insensitive and therefore
>      should be normalized to use uppercase letters for the digits A-F.
>
> When a URI uses components of the generic syntax, the component
>      syntax equivalence rules always apply; namely, that the scheme and
>      host are case-insensitive and therefore should be normalized to
>      lowercase.  For example, the URI  is
>      equivalent to http://www.example.com/.  The other generic syntax
>      components are assumed to be case-sensitive unless specifically
>      defined otherwise by the scheme (see Section 6.2.3).

If you still want to make them case insensitive, you can use a servlet filter and put it in front of JAX-RS framework. You still need to be consistent in your application.

If you consider switching from Jersey to [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/), you can use the [Dynamic Resources](http://tarlogonjava.blogspot.com/2010/03/apache-wink-dynamic-resources.html) to ensure that all urls are lower/upper-cased. So combining a servlet filter with the Dynamic Resources can be a full solution for this case.

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of "easy"

Answer (score 5):

I think I found simple solution which is JAX-RS specification compliant. You are able to use in `@Path` annotation  regular expression like this:

```
@Path("/{message:[mM][eE][sS][aA][gG][eE]}")
```

I have used it with JBoss RESTeasy implemention. See more [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083851/jax-rs-case-insensitive-paths).

Comment: the case-insensitive flag works for me with Jersey 2.10
`@Path( "/{message : (?i)message}" )`