# JAX-RS: case-insensitive paths

Tags: java, annotations, jax-rs, case-insensitive

I have anchored REST services/methods to URI template by `@Path` annotation. It looks like as usual:

```
@GET
@Path("/message")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getMessage() { ... }
```

But my REST service has to be case-insensitive. Now I'm using regular expression in `@Path` in all my code like that:

```
@GET
@Path("/{message:[mM][eE][sS][aA][gG][eE]}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getMessage() { ... }
```

This looks weird. Is there something I overlooked in specification (I hope not, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624481/case-insensitive-urls-with-jax-rs/5625797#5625797)) or has any of JAX-RS implementations special feature for that? Now I'm using [JBoss RESTeasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy).

Thanks.

Comment: Why would your REST service need to be case insensitive? URIs *are* case sensitive as the question you reference points out. If you insist on breaking this, then yeah ... that's probably one way to do it.

Comment: Possible solution here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624481/case-insensitive-urls-with-jax-rs

Comment: I have to implement very same REST API which is implemented in .NET and this API is case insensitive. Second, some REST services over the world are case insensitive, for example Last.fm API.

Comment: The fact that someone else breaks a standard isn't really a good justification for doing the same. If Johnny jumped off a bridge ...

Comment: You are right at this point as we all know, but the customer is always right. Thank you for your opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know resteasy, but if it supports all java regex syntax, you could use `(?i:message)` instead of your pattern.

Comment: Good point! I have tested but it failed on any request with `IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 2`. I have tried `(?i:message)` and `(?i)message`, maybe RESTeasy does some preprocess on templates and counts my non-capturing group. I'll report it to JBoss.

Comment: For next generations :-), problem reported here https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-624

Comment: Aaaaand... fixed in RESTeasy 2.3-beta-2. Now is your answer acceptable :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to make the api case-insensitive and you're using Apache on the front-end of your site, consider doing it outside of code: define your API with the urls all lowercase and use Mod-Rewrite to change the urls to lowercase when they hit the web server no matter what the client actually sent. This [blog post](http://www.chrisabernethy.com/force-lower-case-urls-with-mod_rewrite/) describes how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change case of whole URL. There are parameters and their values in it. Maybe Mod-Rewrite can change it partially, but this pushes logic of application outside to Apache, and this isn't acceptable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the next pattern is working for me:

```
@Path("/{externalorders: (?i)externalorders}")
```