# How to setup path parameter in RESTeasy client

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I have used RESTeasy for server and client. Client shares service interface with server:

```
public interface Service {
    @Path("/start")
    @GET
    void start();
}
```

Implementation of this service is bound to path `/api`, so method start() is accessible on full path `/api/start`. On client side is code pretty straightforward:

```
RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());
Service service = ProxyFactory.create(Service.class, "http://server/api");
service.start();
```

But I want to have path case insensitive, so I fake path parameter with regular expression in it:

```
public interface Service {
    @Path("/{start:[Ss]tart}")
    @GET
    void start();
}
```

Now client ProxyFactory doesn't know value for substitution path parameter `{start}` and doesn't do any substitution and client ends with exception `You did not supply enough values to fill path parameters`.

But when i try to use path parameter as method argument, it works.

```
public interface Service {
    @Path("/{start:[Ss]tart}")
    @GET
    void start(@PathParam("start") String param);
}
```

How can I specify value for fake path parameter in RESTeasy client?

Thanks.

Comment: For those who interested, now I use two separate interfaces for server (with regular expression) and for client (with plain lowercase path). I report it as enhancement to RESTeasy bug tracker, we will see, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-634

Comment: Update: I have switched to Jersey REST server more than year ago. Jersey supports client in completely another way, so I have to face another sort of problems :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the answer here [Case-insensitive URLs with JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624481/case-insensitive-urls-with-jax-rs) : No There this also the attached RFC to this rule

Comment: It's little bit out of date and have already read the answer (and added my answer to that question in fact), but finally I can mark this as answered :)